# How can i determine the instance of my Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, instance

This is my 1st time setting up SQL Server 2008 R2. how could i identify what "Server Name" should i use? I tried the default instance (local) and "." but still it doesn't work. I also tried search on how to get the list of instance but most of the result are for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. I'm not sure if they are similar. Also check the SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Serve Services but there are no items to shown.

Note: I'm not the one who installed the software.

Comment: Try Your pc name or MSSQLSERVER or SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: SQL Express is pretty much the same. Why don't you follow the information you found and postback when you have an issue. If the SQL Server is installed on the local machine then the server name would be `localhost`. There may or may not be an instance name. What happens when you browser in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: I already tried my PC name. same results.
@ElectricLlama I did try them. I wasn't able to determine my "Serve Name" i also tried localhost. I'm stuck at the Connect Server Form.

Comment: Are you setting it up or trying to find the configuration for an already installed server?

Comment: Can i just setup a new configuration? I'm not quite sure if there is a configuration already setup. This is my 1st time to access this.

Comment: Reading through all the threads here.... SQL Server was never installed. Are you trying to install it?

Comment: Base on the answer below the SQL Server was never installed. but I already have this apps. http://oi62.tinypic.com/20r0bkl.jpg

Comment: Yes. Those are _client_ tools, used to _connect_ to a server. You don't have a server installed on your PC. There might be one installed elsewhere though.

Comment: Do i need a separate installer for the serve? or maybe it's a package with the SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: I was able to create a new instance using [this link][1] now I'm connected.


  [1]: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/

Comment: Hi @ElectricLlama i just found out that the server was on a remote server. how could i connect to my remote server using the sql management studio???

Comment: You need to know the name of the remote server, and the instance name of there is one, and you need to have a login into the server. Find those things out.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the services dialog (run `services.msc` from the command line, or find `Administrative Tools > View Local Services` in the control panel).

Find the `SQL Server` service - it contains the instance name in brackets.

If you have `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`, then you're running a default (unnamed) instance - connect to it with your machine name or `(local)` or `.`.

If there's something else other than `MSSQLSERVER` in the brackets, use that instance name to connect to your server: use `.\INSTANCE` or `(local)\INSTANCE` as your server name

Comment: I did your step but on the services.msc i did not see any SQL Server I only fond SQL Server VVS Write

Comment: @MSDIZON: in that case, SQL Server isn't installed - try re-installing it. What exactly did you try to install? Did you possibly only install the SQL Server Express Management Studio? That's just the **Management GUI tool** - but not the actual database **engine**

Comment: Do I still need a Installer? because as of now i don't have any installers with me because i was not the one who installed this. Any other way you could suggest?

Comment: If SQL Server is not installed - then yes, you need an installer to get it installed ..... if you want to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (the free edition), [check out this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438)

Comment: Hi. i did try to re install the sql server. but i had the same result. the services are not yet on the services.msc. i think my installer only install the client tools. is there an installer that will install everything i need?

Comment: From the link I provided in my previous comment, you need to download the file `SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe` (or the `x64` version if you want to run 64-bit) - that's the SQL Server Express **engine** with tools (the Management Studio)

Comment: I just contacted my administrator. He told me that the sql server is on a remote server. is it possible that i could connect my SQL Management Studio to the remote server?

Comment: Yes - type in the appropriate server (and possibly instance) name - and you should be connected!

Comment: server name meaning the on that i use to connect to the remote server the sa PC name of the server?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking - you have to know the **machine name** of the machine running your SQL Server, and if it's not a default setup, you also need the **instance** name of SQL Server. Then connect to that server using `MACHINE-NAME\INSTANCE` as your server name - and provide whatever credentials allow you to connect. I would strongly recommend **NOT** using the `sa` account, not even in development!

Comment: Sorry if I'm confusing you. I'm quite new to this. I already did your instructions but still i cant connect to the remote server. Here is the Error log. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: You have the wrong server and/or instance name. Check with your DBA what exactly you need to use! I really cannot help you here....